# How do you delete a workspace in Visual Studio 2003?

Tags: visual-studio-2003

Disclaimer:
I apologize if this is not an appropriate question to ask here... I saw some similar ones that were answered on here but not this exact question.

Question:
Anyway... Does anybody know how I can delete a workspace in Visual Studio 2003? I brought a project over from source control but now I'm trying to change the local path that it gets brought into, but the field is now grayed out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it... VS2003 doesn't appear to have a very good interface for TFS, so I discovered that I'm able to blow away the workspaces in VS2008.